# Private API for native application

Tags: php, api, private

Is it possible to make a private API to communicate from a native application to a web application ?
Because as the application is installed in the client side, the user can the HTTP request and so he can see the application private key and build a new application based on this key...

Tank you,
Sébastien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit his private API key just to one application, if it's used from another one, deny access to your API

Comment: How can i test if the request come from my application ? with the request header ? But it can be modified before sending the request.

Comment: hmm. when user uses his private key for same thing in different application, does it matteR?

Comment: Practically you cannot implement anything which requires authentication securely without using SSL

Comment: This is not a user private key but an api private key. I want to separate my API into two ones (a public and a private). The private API must only be accessible from my application.

Comment: So I suppose I must send these information by post and not by get even if I use HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

Create session id on client side at first time access and store it on server. on second time of access API check same session id present on server or not if present then get access else denies.